# Counting the number of ways to cover $4 \times n$ board with $1 \times 3$ or $3 \times 1$ dominoes

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I'm trying to solve the problem described in the title by writing down some recurrent relation for the number of ways $T(n)$. It is not very simple, one can not just say that it is $T(n) = 3 \times T(n - 3)$.

What I do is trying to describe the ``complete set of final profiles''. Profile is four numbers $(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4)$ that stand for length of corresponding row.

Let us say, that there are 5 profiles that form this ``complete set'': $T(n) = (n, n, n, n)$, $A_{-1}(n) = (n, n, n, n - 1)$ or $(n - 1, n, n, n)$, $A_{-2}(n) = (n, n, n, n - 2)$ or $(n - 2, n, n, n)$, $A_{+1}(n) = (n, n, n, n + 1)$ or $(n + 1, n, n, n)$, or $A_{+2}(n) = (n, n, n, n  + 2)$ or $(n + 2, n, n, n)$.

Then, I need a system of recurrent relations for these quantities. And this is where problems start. Say, I wish to write:
$$T(n) = 3 T(n - 3) + 2 \times (A_{+2}(n) + A_{+1}(n) + A_{-2}(n - 1) + A_{-1}(n - 2)).$$

In the last bracket I'm trying to count the number of transitions between profiles $A$ and $T$.

But I really don't know if this set is not overfilled? How can I be sure that I don't calculate anything twice? What is the correct choice of these profiles and the correct way to write down relations between them?

Comment: Well, if you have such a collection of recurrent relations you could use them to calculate, say, T(6). If you get the right answer your formula is probably correct.